# Java JFrame updates my screen slow untill I press a key

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am writing a simple game and I am working with java in JFrame. My output looks very bad untill I move the platform at the bottom, it looks like it have not enought update rate untill I press a button update and when I release the key it does the same thing. So this is the complete code with 2 classes:

```
public class BrickBreaker {
    private static final String TITLE = "break ball";
    private static final int X = 200, Y = 200, WIDTH = 700, HEIGHT = 600;

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        GamePlay gp = new GamePlay();
        window.setBounds(X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        window.setTitle(TITLE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.add(gp);

    }
}

public class GamePlay extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    private boolean play = false;
    private int score = 0, totalBricks = 21, delay = 10;
    private int playerX = 310;
    private int ballX = 120, ballY = 350, ballDirX = -1, ballDirY = -2;
    private final Timer TIMER;

    public GamePlay(){
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        TIMER = new Timer(delay, this);
        TIMER.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        //Background
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(1,1,700,592);

        //Borders
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(0,0,3,592);
        g.fillRect(697,0,3,592);
        g.fillRect(0,0,697,3);

        //Paddle
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(playerX, 550, 100, 8);

        //Ball
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval(ballX, ballY, 20, 20);

        g.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        TIMER.start();
        if (play){
            TIMER.start();
            ballX += ballDirX;
            ballY += ballDirY;

            if(ballX <= 0 || ballX >= 700){
                ballDirX = - ballDirX;
            }

            if(ballY <= 0 || ballY >= 600){
                ballDirY = -ballDirY;
            }
        }

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            if(playerX >= 590){
                playerX = 590;
            }else{
                moveRight();
            }
        }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            if(playerX <= 10){
                playerX = 10;
            }else{
                moveLeft();
            }
        }
    }

    private void moveLeft() {
        play = true;
        playerX -= 20;
    }

    private void moveRight() {
        play = true;
        playerX += 20;
    }


}
```

I want to know how to smooth the movement of the ball to be always at the rate of the keypressed state.

Comment: `g.dispose();` ← Remove that.  Never dispose of a Graphics object which you didn’t create!  That Graphics instance belongs to AWT/Swing, not you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is no need to start the Timer in the ActionListener. You already start the Timer in the constructor.

> JFrame updates my screen slow untill I press a key

There is no animation at all when I run the code.

Lets do some basic debugging:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(Play); // basic debugging
```

What do you see?

Then what happens when you press an arrow key?

Why do you only set the play variable in the moveRight/moveLeft methods?

Comment: I did it by putting in the if statement always true but it didn't work. I set the walue of start only when I press an arrow because when I press the arrow this application should start to work. When  I press the arrow the play variable becames always true and continue to repeat.

Comment: If you are suggesting you only want the animation when the key is pressed then you need to Start the Timer when the key is pressed and then Stop the Timer when the key is released. There is not need for the "play" variable. The Timer will control the animation. See [Motion Using Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and working examples.

Comment: this is very helpfull but I can't understand why there is an output lag only when I don't press any key

Comment: @KrzysztofWitkowski I don't know what you mean by "output lag". As I stated in my answer there is NO movement until you press a key. In your original code the "play" variable is false, so the logic to change the location of the ball is never invoked.